# What is the portion of the students in the class having brown hair of the following problem?

Tags: arithmetic

**Problem :** In a class, $15 \%$ of the boys have brown hair and $10 \%$ of the girls have brown hair. If the ratio of boys to girls in the class is $4: 3 ;$ then what is the portion of the students in the class having brown hair?

[image]
**Attempt:** Boys=$\frac{4}{7}$, girls=$\frac{3}{7}$.

Required answer= $\frac{4}{7}\times \frac{15}{100}+\frac{3}{7}\times \frac{10}{100}= \frac{9}{70}$

Is the my solution correct?

Comment: Please try to give your questions more descriptive titles.  Almost any question on this site could use that title.  You answer looks right.

Comment: This answer assumes that each student must be either a boy or a girl, not both.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the solution is right.

Boys are $\frac{4}{7}$ of the entire class. Brown hair boys are $\frac{15}{100}$ of the entire amount of boys. Thus, brown hair boys are $\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{15}{100}$ of the entire class.

Similarly for girls:
Girls are $\frac{3}{7}$ of the entire class. Brown hair girls are $\frac{10}{100}$ of the entire amount of girls. Thus, brown hair girls are $\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{10}{100}$ of the entire class.

Brown hair people in class equal brown hair boys plus brown hair girls:

$\frac{4}{7}\cdot\frac{15}{100}+\frac{3}{7}\cdot\frac{10}{100}=\frac{60}{700}+\frac{30}{700}=\frac{9}{70}$

Comment: @ AnastasijaSerova None of the option is matching!!

Comment: @MKS All of the options are wrong - assuming there are only boys and girls in the class, the proportion in the class as a whole must be somewhere between the proportion for boys (15%) and the proportion for girls (10%). All of the options are above 15% or below 10%, but you can't increase the prevalence from a boy-only class by adding girls, nor can you decrease the prevalence from a girl-only class by adding boys. The answer must be somewhere between 10% and 15%.

Comment: @NuclearHoagie that looks like it would work well as an answer here - it's certainly much more of an explanation than the post you're commenting on.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is correct - all of the given answers are wrong.

Assuming there are only boys and girls in the class, the proportion in the class as a whole must be somewhere between the proportion for boys (15%) and the proportion for girls (10%). All of the options are above 15% or below 10%, but you can't increase the prevalence from a boy-only class by adding girls, nor can you decrease the prevalence from a girl-only class by adding boys. The correct solution is a weighted average of proportions, and you'll always find the average of two numbers is *between* those numbers, regardless of the weights. The answer must be somewhere between 10% and 15%, but all of the options are above 15%.